# canvas not working in ie8 browsers

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs, canvasjs

- My canvas not working in ie8 i include explorer canvas js file and
  included the script tag in my html... i downloaded from this link 
  https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/downloads/list can you guys
  tell me how to fix this bug... providing my code below...or is there a way to fix the bug

http://jsfiddle.net/fHmA8/1/

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.craftygnome.com/fixes/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

```js
var animate = function() {
        canvas.width = canvas.width;    //clear canvas

        percent += STEP_PERCENT;    //increase percentage
        var deg = percent / 100 * deg360;   //calculate current position in radians

        drawArc('#aaa', radius, deg360, null, true);    //draw grey background (last parameter - true - draw shadow)
        drawArc('#0e728e', radius, deg);                //draw light blue
        for (var i = 0, n = Math.floor(deg / deg60); i < n; i++) {  //draw segments (as I understand segment drawing works not exactly as you want so you can delete this code)
            var from = i * deg30 + deg1;
            var to = from + deg30 - deg1 * 2;
            drawArc('#250696', radius, to, from);
        }

        if (percent >= 100) {
            //done
        } else {
            setTimeout(animate, STEP_DELAY);    //next step in STEP_DELAY ms
        }
    }
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: thanks for your reply...the problem is from the script tag...i have put my code in fiddle also..

Comment: Yes, pre-IE9 is a bear.  If animated percentage arcs are the extent of your needs, you might seriously consider SVG + RaphaelJS as an alternative.

Comment: @markE: I looked into RaphaelJs its little bit confusing...can you pls update in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fHmA8/1/

Comment: I suggest SVG and RaphaelJS because that's what I use in those rare occasions I can't convince a client to upgrade their browsers. Microsoft is ending support for XP (and therefore IE8) in April (yes, next month!). They are automatically upgrading IE8 to IE9+ where possible during their automatic updates.  MY 2 CENTS:  I would strongly suggest you lean on your client a bit and get them to upgrade to IE9+ rather than using excanvas to patch a browser that's been phased out.

Comment: @markE: thanks for your reply...if you update in fiddle that would be great

Comment: My experience with excanvas was that it barely worked, and those parts which worked had abysmal performance. When you want canvas, better accept that it won't work on IE <9.

Comment: @Philipp: I am trying to achieve using chart js...since chart js supports ie8...but not able to achive it...can you tell me how to fix it.. http://jsfiddle.net/fHmA8/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to initialize the canvas depending on when it is created. You can do that by calling these lines -

After obtaining the "canvas" element in the top of the script:

```
// initialize if excanvas
if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager !== 'undefined')
    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);

// now this should work
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

... continue code here...
```