# Canvas error in IE8

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-8, html5-canvas

I've have canvas which renders 2 circles (a Venn Diagram to be specific).

The canvas must support IE8 so as a fallback, I included [Excanvas.js](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) and HTML5shiv, however I'm getting the error>

> Object doesn't support this property or method on on line 21

The line of code which belong on line 21 is:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

This is my first time working with a canvas so I'm rather clueless as to why it isn't working as I know there are ways of getting it to work in IE8.

Here is a SOFiddle:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

  <!--[if IE]>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/excanvas/r3/excanvas.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

  <canvas id="canvas" width="260" height="140"></canvas>

  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

    // Calculate the circle positions
    var rawPercentage = '25%';
    var percentage = rawPercentage.replace('%', '');

    var calculateWhiteX = ((percentage / 100) * 65) + 65;
    var calculateGreyX = 196 - ((percentage / 100) * 65);


    var circleWhite = {
      x: calculateWhiteX, // top/bottom
      y: 65, // left/right
      r: 64 // radius/size
    };
    var circleGrey = {
      x: calculateGreyX, // top/bottom
      y: 65, // left/right
      r: 64 // radius/size
    };

    var grey = '#e8e9e9';
    var white = '#FFFFFF';
    var blue = '#1f4e80';

    drawCircle(ctx, circleGrey, grey);
    drawCircle(ctx, circleWhite, white);

    function drawIntersect(a, b, c, notC, color) {

      ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);

      ctx1.save();

      // a
      drawCircle(ctx1, a, color);
      // b
      ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
      drawCircle(ctx1, b, color);
      // c
      if (c) {
        drawCircle(ctx1, c, color);
      }
      // notC
      ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
      if (notC) {
        drawCircle(ctx1, notC, color);
      }

      ctx1.restore();
      ctx.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0);
    }

    function drawCircle(ctx, circle, color) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fill();
      genStroke();
    }

    function genStroke() {
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#d2d2d2';
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    function drawVenn() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      drawCircle(ctx, circleGrey, grey);
      drawCircle(ctx, circleWhite, white);
      drawIntersect(circleWhite, circleGrey, null, null, blue);
    }

    drawVenn();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone shed some light and possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285569/canvas-not-working-in-ie8-browsers/22293779#22293779

Answer (score 1):

**You might consider workarounds for IE<9 like:**

- Although statistics vary, IE<9 market share is small...less than 2% according to: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp). . Tell your employer politely but firmly that efforts to support outdated browsers with tiny market share is not worth that effort. Consider this a public service to the programming community you're part of.  Microsoft itself is not keeping IE<9 alive so efforts to shim IE<9 cause all of us programmers to be held back from useful programming.
- Provide static pages and inform the user that they will have a better experience if they upgrade to a modern browser.
- Create your Venn diagrams on the server using a "headless browser" and serve them to your page as an image. PhantomJS is a good headless browser: http://phantomjs.org/
- Use SVG instead of html Canvas as your display element. SVG has drawing commands that mirror the canvas drawing commands. Microsoft included semi-support for SVG in IE8 with their VML drawing commands. RaphaelJS is library which lets you code using SVG drawing commands and it automatically outputs VML on IE<9:  http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, not support IE8 is out of the question as the client is an extremely big world wide company, with users that still use IE8. I narrowed down the issue. It's not displaying due to `canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas"); ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");`. Removing this code draws the white and grey circles, but does not show the intersect.

Comment: I understand the pressures of "big world-wide" clients and I wish you well in serving the diminishing IE<9 user base, but as a company we no longer support IE<9.  I suggest you use PhantomJS to create your diagrams rather than trying to shim with ExCanvas. Good luck with your project!